# Save cookie on OwlCarousel slide item jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies, slider, owl-carousel

I have an owl carousel listing all products, every image leads to a single page. I want a cookie to be saved, so when the user clicks on an image and then decides to go back, the carousel will remember where the user were in the carousel.

Example: user clicks on slide number 5 and enters its single page, changes its mind, goes back and then slide number 5 is in position number one in the carousel. Do I make any sense?

The code for the carousel is this:

```
<div class="loop owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item" id="<?php the_title();?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Click to view: <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <div class="image-container <?php if( get_field('full-image') ): ?> full-image <?php endif; ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                <div class="hover-bg"></div>
                <div class="hover-text">
                    <p><?php the_field('short');?></p>
                    <p style="margin-top: 20px !important;"><?php the_field('procent');?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

I would use localStorage instead of cookies. Here's a jQuery solution.

```js
<script>

//CHECKS WHETHER OR NOT THERE'S A KEY/VALUE PAIR NAMED 'mostRecentPic' STORED IN localStorage. IF NOT THEN ON CLICKING A CAROUSEL IMAGE THE VALUE OF ITS SOURCE ATTRIBUTE IS STORED IN A KEY/VALUE PAIR IN localStorage, WITH THE KEY BEING 'mostRecentPic'. ELSE IF THE KEY/VALUE PAIR ALREADY EXISTS THE VALUE OF THE KEY (THE VALUE OF THE SRC ATTRIBUTE) IS ASSIGNED AS THE VALUE OF THE SRC ATTRIBUTE OF THE FIRST IMAGE IN THE CAROUSEL. 

if (!localStorage.getItem("mostRecentPic")) {
    $(".owl-carousel img").click( function() {
        localStorage.setItem("mostRecentPic", $(this).attr("src"));
    });
 } else {
      $(".owl-carousel img:first-child").attr("src", localStorage.getItem("mostRecentPic"));
 }
 
 </script>
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work, dont know how to debug it either. I get no error message in the console.

Comment: Can you share your final generated HTML please?

Comment: What do you mean? How the code looks in the inspector?

Comment: Exactly. Because I'm using jQuery to manipulate the front-end I need to know exactly what it looks like for the client.

Comment: Sorry for a latte reply. I found out that what the above code do is that it takes one of the sliders (the page have 4 sliders in total) and fill it with the first image of the first slider. The final generated HTML is a lot of code...